# Variable not updating its value when Returning it

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, return

I have some HTML checkboxes and I have selected them inside Javascript using an Array. Each of those checkboxes has a different price and after looping through the 'selected ones' the final price only updates inside the function. If I try to use it outside, it returns '0' (the initial value).

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Cheese Topping - £0.20" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Cheese<span>£0.20</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms Topping - £0.40" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Mushrooms<span>£0.40</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Ham Topping - £0.50" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Ham<span>£0.50</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Anchovies Topping - £0.60" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Anchovies<span>£0.60</span></p>
```

JS:

```
// Pizza Topping Order
var topping_prices = new Array();
    topping_prices["Cheese Topping - £0.20"] = 0.2;
    topping_prices["Mushrooms Topping - £0.40"] = 0.4;
    topping_prices["Ham Topping - £0.50"] = 0.5;
    topping_prices["Anchovies Topping - £0.60"] = 0.6;

function Topping_Order(){
  var topping_price = 0;
  var selected_topping = theForm.elements["topping"];
  for (var i = 0; i< selected_topping.length; i++){
    if (selected_topping[i].checked == true){
      topping_price = topping_price + topping_prices[selected_topping[i].value];
    }
  }
  console.log("Total price inside the function is: £" + topping_price.toFixed(2));
  return topping_price;
}
var topping_order_value = Topping_Order();
console.log("Total price outside the function is: £" + topping_order_value.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: the topping_price variable updates in real time inside the function. if I want to use it outside of the function, it returns 0 ( the initial value).

Comment: How do you want to use it outside? You mean show the updated value on UI?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you look at the code, I have 2 console logs. The first console log (inside the function) updates in real-time based on checkboxes selection. The second one uses the same variable but returned from the function. I just need to use the updated version of the price, outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use the `topping_order_value` after the first call to `Topping_Order()`.

You need to call `Topping_Order()` and use its return value:

```js
var topping_prices = new Array();
topping_prices["Cheese Topping - £0.20"] = 0.2;
topping_prices["Mushrooms Topping - £0.40"] = 0.4;
topping_prices["Ham Topping - £0.50"] = 0.5;
topping_prices["Anchovies Topping - £0.60"] = 0.6;

function Topping_Order() {
  var topping_price = 0;
  var selected_topping = theForm.elements["topping"];
  for (var i = 0; i < selected_topping.length; i++) {
    if (selected_topping[i].checked == true) {
      topping_price = topping_price + topping_prices[selected_topping[i].value];
    }
  }
  console.log("Total price inside the function is: £" + topping_price.toFixed(2));
  return topping_price;
}

function updateToppingPrice() {
  var topping_price = Topping_Order();
  
  console.log(topping_price.toFixed(2));
  var el = document.getElementById('total');
  el.innerHTML = topping_price.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  
  <div class="size">
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Cheese Topping - £0.20" onclick="updateToppingPrice();">
  Cheese<span>£0.20</span></div>
  
  <div class="size">
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms Topping - £0.40" onclick="updateToppingPrice();">
  Mushrooms<span>£0.40</span></div>
  
  <div class="size">
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Ham Topping - £0.50" onclick="updateToppingPrice();">
  Ham<span>£0.50</span></div>
  
  <div class="size">
  <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Anchovies Topping - £0.60" onclick="updateToppingPrice();">
  Anchovies<span>£0.60</span></div>
</form>

<p id="total">...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment

> Basically, yes. If you look at the code, I have 2 console logs. The
>   first console log (inside the function) updates in real-time based on
>   checkboxes selection. The second one uses the same variable but
>   returned from the function. I just need to use the updated version of
>   the price, outside the function

Your outer `console.log` doesn't get latest value since every time you invoke `Topping_Order`, **since the statements which are not defined in `Topping_Order` doesn't get executed** and the local variable `topping_price` is not accessible outside.

You can show this value on another element

```
<p id="finalValue"></p>
```

and add this line to `Topping_Order`

```
document.getElementById( "finalValue" ).innerHTML = "Total price inside the function is: £" + topping_price.toFixed(2);
```

**Demo**

```js
// Pizza Topping Order
var topping_prices = new Array();
    topping_prices["Cheese Topping - £0.20"] = 0.2;
    topping_prices["Mushrooms Topping - £0.40"] = 0.4;
    topping_prices["Ham Topping - £0.50"] = 0.5;
    topping_prices["Anchovies Topping - £0.60"] = 0.6;

function Topping_Order(){
  var topping_price = 0;
  var selected_topping = document.querySelectorAll('[name="topping"]');
  for (var i = 0; i< selected_topping.length; i++){
    if (selected_topping[i].checked == true){
      topping_price = topping_price + topping_prices[selected_topping[i].value];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById( "finalValue" ).innerHTML = "Total price inside the function is: £" + topping_price.toFixed(2);
  return topping_price;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Cheese Topping - £0.20" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Cheese<span>£0.20</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms Topping - £0.40" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Mushrooms<span>£0.40</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Ham Topping - £0.50" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Ham<span>£0.50</span></p><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Anchovies Topping - £0.60" onclick="Topping_Order();">
<p class="size">Anchovies<span>£0.60</span></p>

<p id="finalValue"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

var topping_order_value = Topping_Order();(Will get triggerd on load)

In your JS File, when above line trigger the function call you dont have topping selected because of that it will return initial value 0

When you selected checkbox onclick it triggers function call at that time you have some tooping checked so will return updated value